# Unusual Door Mechanics At Play

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, kinematics, temperature, torque

We have a door in our Applied mathematics lecture venue, that seems to open and close itself randomly (at about a 1-2 min interval). The door is not electrical and there is nobody pushing it from behind. The lecture venue is 2 floors up from the ground level.

For clarity sake, the amount that the door opens is a fraction of a meter, approximately 30-40 cm, going both directions and remaining stationary for approximately 8-13 seconds . The question I am posing here is how is this phenomenon happening? Is there some underlying physics that im not aware of at play here?

Comment: Maybe air pressure? (Incidentally, is the door [latched](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latch_(hardware)#Spring_latches) and is there a spring/damper that would slowly shut the door automatically?)

Comment: It's not pressure. There were instances where the door opened even when the windows were wide open. Even if it were pressure, that wouldn't explain why it remains stationary after opening and then swings back to its rest position. I'll make a vid tomorrow and post it on YouTube, and then post the link so you can see what I'm talking about

Answer (score 1):

It is likely air pressure. If the building has an air control system then it is possible for pressure differentials to form in different parts of the building (such as the lecture venue and the hall outside of it). If for some reason a pressure differential is created in the direction to push the door open the door will push open if the differential is large enough and the door is not latched. Why would this happen with such regularity? The pressure in the hall outside the lecture room could change because someone opened the door of a nearby room and there was an airflow equilibration between those two rooms changing the pressure in the hall and thus creating a larger pressure differential. Or perhaps someone opened a door to the outside with the same effect. If the door to the room immediately goes outside or if windows are open then the wind picking up could change the pressure gradient on either side of the door. Note that the wind doesn't have to be "pushing" on the door to open it. Because of Bernoulli's principle even if the wind was flowing perpendicularly past a door or window that could create a pressure differential which might change the pressure balance in the building thus opening the door.

edit: If the interval is VERY regular then it is possible that the air control system is driving serious pressure differentials in different parts of the building which are being periodically equilibrated when the door is forced open, like an overpressure valve. If you hold the door shut you would notice a lot of wind blowing through the cracks in or out if this is the case. I've seen problems like this in my building where it gets to the point that it is actually very difficult to open a door. At that level it is worth informing a building manager of the problem. Somehow I doubt this is the case for the situation you are describing.

Comment: It's not the pressure. The phenomenon still happened even while the windows were open. I'll post a vid tomorrow of the phenomenon so you may see it

Comment: It could still be pressure + friction even with the window open. What is outside the door? Is it a hallway or the outdoors? Oh I guess it’s a Hall since you said second floor. Does the door open into or out of the room?

Comment: Both ways. It oscillates back and forth